# Ethereum known states

Tags: go-ethereum

I've been trying to sync my ETH node for some days now, but I am noticing it is taking too long. Can anyone of you who has a full node tell me how many knownStates there are? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

About 900 million state objects, as of today. This is a very aprox number and it is increasing every day

```
knownStates: 752662999,
```

Depending on your SSD speed for RANDOM iops (note the random condition) the sync (fast sync) can take about 2 months or a few days

Comment: Wait I didn’t understand, are there 900 million or 752 million states?

Comment: 900 million, 750 is what I had few months ago